# Pitting / bleach staining on bathroom taps

Tags: cleaning

Trying to get an old bathroom looking much nicer, and our bath mixer tap has been quite badly stained / tarnished, I believe someone put bleach on it at one point and obviously it's had quite an impact.

I've had a look at a few cleaning products but nothing seems to have worked – is there anything anyone can suggest to get these taps sparkling again?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That Looks like lime scale or soap scum. try white vinegar, or a similar proprietary lime remover.

Comment: This would have been my answer.+

Answer (score 0):

Once the plating on the metal parts has corroded like shown in the picture it is not going to be possible to get it looking like it originally did.

You could try cleaning away the corrosion by using steel wool to buff the surface. In this case it may require a course grade of steel wool and then working toward a finer grade. This will likely get you back to a shiny base metal look but this is going to be a temporary fix because once the plating is gone the base metal is susceptible to oxidation or reacting with water.

Comment: brass wool would be a better choice, as steel can scratch the finish.